# bluetooth android server socket issue

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

Am having great issues with building a client server model for my Bluetooth application. I run my Bluetooth server application on a mobile. Here is the code for that:
public class BlueSer extends Activity {

```
 /** Called when the activity is first created. */
 private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = null;
 private static final UUID MY_UUID =
 UUID.fromString("fa87c0d0-afac-11de-8a39-0800200c9a66");
 private byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
 private ImageView image;

 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.blueserv);
 image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

 mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
 if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
 Toast.makeText(this,
 "Bluetooth is not available.",
 Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 finish();
 return;
 }

if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
 Toast.makeText(this,
 "Please enable your BT and re-run this program.",
 Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 finish();
 return;
 }
Log.w("Thread Started: ", "Thread ka start hai jani");
 AcceptData acceptData = new AcceptData();
 acceptData.start();
 Bitmap bm1 = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
 image.setImageBitmap(bm1);
 }

 class AcceptData extends Thread{
 private final BluetoothServerSocket mmServerSocket;
 private BluetoothSocket socket = null;
 private InputStream mmInStream;
 private String device;
 public AcceptData() {
 BluetoothServerSocket tmp = null;
 try {
 tmp = mBluetoothAdapter.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord("Bluetooth", MY_UUID);
 } catch (IOException e) {
     Log.w("Display Hona Chahye", "Kr dia na display Rami");
 //
 }
 mmServerSocket = tmp;
 try {
 socket = mmServerSocket.accept();
 } catch (IOException e) {
 //
 }
 Log.w("iudfghiue", "yaiiii");
 device = socket.getRemoteDevice().getName();
 Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Connected to " + device, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 InputStream tmpIn = null;
 try {
 tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
 } catch (IOException e) {
 //
 }
 mmInStream = tmpIn;
 int byteNo;
 try {
 byteNo = mmInStream.read(buffer);
 if (byteNo != -1) {
 //ensure DATAMAXSIZE Byte is read.
 int byteNo2 = byteNo;
 int bufferSize = 7340;
 while(byteNo2 != bufferSize){
 bufferSize = bufferSize - byteNo2;
 byteNo2 = mmInStream.read(buffer,byteNo,bufferSize);
 if(byteNo2 == -1){
 break;
 }
 byteNo = byteNo+byteNo2;
 }
 }
 if (socket != null) {
 try {
 mmServerSocket.close();
 } catch (IOException e) {
 //
 }
 }
 }
 catch (Exception e) {
 // TODO: handle exception
 }
}
}

}
```

The logcat is as follows:

```
12-23 01:32:34.292: D/ServiceManager(1264): The name of the service is bluetooth
12-23 01:32:34.293: W/Thread Started:(1264): Thread ka start hai jani
12-23 01:32:34.294: I/BluetoothSocket_MTK(1264): [JSR82] Bluetooth Socket Constructor
12-23 01:32:34.294: I/BluetoothSocket_MTK(1264): [JSR82] type=1 fd=-1 auth=true encrypt=true port=4
12-23 01:32:34.294: D/ServiceManager(1264): The name of the service is bluetooth_socket
**12-23 01:32:34.295: I/BluetoothSocket_MTK(1264): [JSR82] bindListen
12-23 01:32:34.296: D/BluetoothSocket_MTK(1264): [JSR82] bindListen: bindListen() failed.
12-23 01:32:34.298: I/BluetoothSocket_MTK(1264): [JSR82] accept().
12-23 01:32:34.299: I/BluetoothSocket_MTK(1264): [JSR82] accept: Connection is not created.**
12-23 01:32:34.299: W/iudfghiue(1264): yaiiii
12-23 01:32:34.299: D/AndroidRuntime(1264): Shutting down VM
12-23 01:32:34.299: W/dalvikvm(1264): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x413ad9a8)
12-23 01:32:34.305: E/AndroidRuntime(1264): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-23 01:32:34.305: E/AndroidRuntime(1264): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.BlueSer/com.example.blueserv.BlueSer}: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-23 01:32:34.305: E/AndroidRuntime(1264):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2313)
12-23 01:32:34.305: E/AndroidRuntime(1264):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2365)
12-23 01:32:34.305: E/AndroidRuntime(1264):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:156)
12-23 01:32:34.305: E/AndroidRuntime(1264):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
12-23 01:32:34.305: E/AndroidRuntime(1264):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-23 01:32:34.305: E/AndroidRuntime(1264):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
12-23 01:32:34.305: E/AndroidRuntime(1264):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5336)
12-23 01:32:34.305: E/AndroidRuntime(1264):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-23 01:32:34.305: E/AndroidRuntime(1264):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-23 01:32:34.305: E/AndroidRuntime(1264):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
```

Now if I focus at the logcat my program is throwing exception because it is not able to listen to some device. I have already paired that device with the other android device. Just cannot figure out what is the issue. Please help. These seem to be the troubling lines of the code:

```
tmp = mBluetoothAdapter.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord("Bluetooth", MY_UUID);
         } catch (IOException e) {
             Log.w("Display Hona Chahye", "Kr dia na display Rami");
         //
         }
         mmServerSocket = tmp;
         try {
         socket = mmServerSocket.accept();
```

Where I have kept the UUID's string same in both the client and server code!

Answer (score 0):

This works for me 
Or you can reference [this](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-BluetoothChat) library for more details about the flow

```
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothServerSocket;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;

import com.example.android.common.logger.Log;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.UUID;

/**
 * This class does all the work for setting up and managing Bluetooth
 * connections with other devices. It has a thread that listens for
 * incoming connections, a thread for connecting with a device, and a
 * thread for performing data transmissions when connected.
 */
public class BluetoothChatService {
    // Debugging
    private static final String TAG = "BluetoothChatService";

    // Name for the SDP record when creating server socket
    private static final String NAME_SECURE = "BluetoothChatSecure";
    private static final String NAME_INSECURE = "BluetoothChatInsecure";

    // Unique UUID for this application
    private static final UUID MY_UUID_SECURE =
            UUID.fromString("fa87c0d0-afac-11de-8a39-0800200c9a66");
    private static final UUID MY_UUID_INSECURE =
            UUID.fromString("8ce255c0-200a-11e0-ac64-0800200c9a66");

    // Member fields
    private final BluetoothAdapter mAdapter;
    private final Handler mHandler;
    private AcceptThread mSecureAcceptThread;
    private AcceptThread mInsecureAcceptThread;
    private ConnectThread mConnectThread;
    private ConnectedThread mConnectedThread;
    private int mState;

    // Constants that indicate the current connection state
    public static final int STATE_NONE = 0;       // we're doing nothing
    public static final int STATE_LISTEN = 1;     // now listening for incoming connections
    public static final int STATE_CONNECTING = 2; // now initiating an outgoing connection
    public static final int STATE_CONNECTED = 3;  // now connected to a remote device

    /**
     * Constructor. Prepares a new BluetoothChat session.
     *
     * @param context The UI Activity Context
     * @param handler A Handler to send messages back to the UI Activity
     */
    public BluetoothChatService(Context context, Handler handler) {
        mAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        mState = STATE_NONE;
        mHandler = handler;
    }

    /**
     * Set the current state of the chat connection
     *
     * @param state An integer defining the current connection state
     */
    private synchronized void setState(int state) {
        Log.d(TAG, "setState() " + mState + " -> " + state);
        mState = state;

        // Give the new state to the Handler so the UI Activity can update
        mHandler.obtainMessage(Constants.MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE, state, -1).sendToTarget();
    }

    /**
     * Return the current connection state.
     */
    public synchronized int getState() {
        return mState;
    }

    /**
     * Start the chat service. Specifically start AcceptThread to begin a
     * session in listening (server) mode. Called by the Activity onResume()
     */
    public synchronized void start() {
        Log.d(TAG, "start");

        // Cancel any thread attempting to make a connection
        if (mConnectThread != null) {
            mConnectThread.cancel();
            mConnectThread = null;
        }

        // Cancel any thread currently running a connection
        if (mConnectedThread != null) {
            mConnectedThread.cancel();
            mConnectedThread = null;
        }

        setState(STATE_LISTEN);

        // Start the thread to listen on a BluetoothServerSocket
        if (mSecureAcceptThread == null) {
            mSecureAcceptThread = new AcceptThread(true);
            mSecureAcceptThread.start();
        }
        if (mInsecureAcceptThread == null) {
            mInsecureAcceptThread = new AcceptThread(false);
            mInsecureAcceptThread.start();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Start the ConnectThread to initiate a connection to a remote device.
     *
     * @param device The BluetoothDevice to connect
     * @param secure Socket Security type - Secure (true) , Insecure (false)
     */
    public synchronized void connect(BluetoothDevice device, boolean secure) {
        Log.d(TAG, "connect to: " + device);

        // Cancel any thread attempting to make a connection
        if (mState == STATE_CONNECTING) {
            if (mConnectThread != null) {
                mConnectThread.cancel();
                mConnectThread = null;
            }
        }

        // Cancel any thread currently running a connection
        if (mConnectedThread != null) {
            mConnectedThread.cancel();
            mConnectedThread = null;
        }

        // Start the thread to connect with the given device
        mConnectThread = new ConnectThread(device, secure);
        mConnectThread.start();
        setState(STATE_CONNECTING);
    }

    /**
     * Start the ConnectedThread to begin managing a Bluetooth connection
     *
     * @param socket The BluetoothSocket on which the connection was made
     * @param device The BluetoothDevice that has been connected
     */
    public synchronized void connected(BluetoothSocket socket, BluetoothDevice
            device, final String socketType) {
        Log.d(TAG, "connected, Socket Type:" + socketType);

        // Cancel the thread that completed the connection
        if (mConnectThread != null) {
            mConnectThread.cancel();
            mConnectThread = null;
        }

        // Cancel any thread currently running a connection
        if (mConnectedThread != null) {
            mConnectedThread.cancel();
            mConnectedThread = null;
        }

        // Cancel the accept thread because we only want to connect to one device
        if (mSecureAcceptThread != null) {
            mSecureAcceptThread.cancel();
            mSecureAcceptThread = null;
        }
        if (mInsecureAcceptThread != null) {
            mInsecureAcceptThread.cancel();
            mInsecureAcceptThread = null;
        }

        // Start the thread to manage the connection and perform transmissions
        mConnectedThread = new ConnectedThread(socket, socketType);
        mConnectedThread.start();

        // Send the name of the connected device back to the UI Activity
        Message msg = mHandler.obtainMessage(Constants.MESSAGE_DEVICE_NAME);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString(Constants.DEVICE_NAME, device.getName());
        msg.setData(bundle);
        mHandler.sendMessage(msg);

        setState(STATE_CONNECTED);
    }

    /**
     * Stop all threads
     */
    public synchronized void stop() {
        Log.d(TAG, "stop");

        if (mConnectThread != null) {
            mConnectThread.cancel();
            mConnectThread = null;
        }

        if (mConnectedThread != null) {
            mConnectedThread.cancel();
            mConnectedThread = null;
        }

        if (mSecureAcceptThread != null) {
            mSecureAcceptThread.cancel();
            mSecureAcceptThread = null;
        }

        if (mInsecureAcceptThread != null) {
            mInsecureAcceptThread.cancel();
            mInsecureAcceptThread = null;
        }
        setState(STATE_NONE);
    }

    /**
     * Write to the ConnectedThread in an unsynchronized manner
     *
     * @param out The bytes to write
     * @see ConnectedThread#write(byte[])
     */
    public void write(byte[] out) {
        // Create temporary object
        ConnectedThread r;
        // Synchronize a copy of the ConnectedThread
        synchronized (this) {
            if (mState != STATE_CONNECTED) return;
            r = mConnectedThread;
        }
        // Perform the write unsynchronized
        r.write(out);
    }

    /**
     * Indicate that the connection attempt failed and notify the UI Activity.
     */
    private void connectionFailed() {
        // Send a failure message back to the Activity
        Message msg = mHandler.obtainMessage(Constants.MESSAGE_TOAST);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString(Constants.TOAST, "Unable to connect device");
        msg.setData(bundle);
        mHandler.sendMessage(msg);

        // Start the service over to restart listening mode
        BluetoothChatService.this.start();
    }

    /**
     * Indicate that the connection was lost and notify the UI Activity.
     */
    private void connectionLost() {
        // Send a failure message back to the Activity
        Message msg = mHandler.obtainMessage(Constants.MESSAGE_TOAST);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString(Constants.TOAST, "Device connection was lost");
        msg.setData(bundle);
        mHandler.sendMessage(msg);

        // Start the service over to restart listening mode
        BluetoothChatService.this.start();
    }

    /**
     * This thread runs while listening for incoming connections. It behaves
     * like a server-side client. It runs until a connection is accepted
     * (or until cancelled).
     */
    private class AcceptThread extends Thread {
        // The local server socket
        private final BluetoothServerSocket mmServerSocket;
        private String mSocketType;

        public AcceptThread(boolean secure) {
            BluetoothServerSocket tmp = null;
            mSocketType = secure ? "Secure" : "Insecure";

            // Create a new listening server socket
            try {
                if (secure) {
                    tmp = mAdapter.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord(NAME_SECURE,
                            MY_UUID_SECURE);
                } else {
                    tmp = mAdapter.listenUsingInsecureRfcommWithServiceRecord(
                            NAME_INSECURE, MY_UUID_INSECURE);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Socket Type: " + mSocketType + "listen() failed", e);
            }
            mmServerSocket = tmp;
        }

        public void run() {
            Log.d(TAG, "Socket Type: " + mSocketType +
                    "BEGIN mAcceptThread" + this);
            setName("AcceptThread" + mSocketType);

            BluetoothSocket socket = null;

            // Listen to the server socket if we're not connected
            while (mState != STATE_CONNECTED) {
                try {
                    // This is a blocking call and will only return on a
                    // successful connection or an exception
                    socket = mmServerSocket.accept();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Socket Type: " + mSocketType + "accept() failed", e);
                    break;
                }

                // If a connection was accepted
                if (socket != null) {
                    synchronized (BluetoothChatService.this) {
                        switch (mState) {
                            case STATE_LISTEN:
                            case STATE_CONNECTING:
                                // Situation normal. Start the connected thread.
                                connected(socket, socket.getRemoteDevice(),
                                        mSocketType);
                                break;
                            case STATE_NONE:
                            case STATE_CONNECTED:
                                // Either not ready or already connected. Terminate new socket.
                                try {
                                    socket.close();
                                } catch (IOException e) {
                                    Log.e(TAG, "Could not close unwanted socket", e);
                                }
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            Log.i(TAG, "END mAcceptThread, socket Type: " + mSocketType);

        }

        public void cancel() {
            Log.d(TAG, "Socket Type" + mSocketType + "cancel " + this);
            try {
                mmServerSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Socket Type" + mSocketType + "close() of server failed", e);
            }
        }
    }


    /**
     * This thread runs while attempting to make an outgoing connection
     * with a device. It runs straight through; the connection either
     * succeeds or fails.
     */
    private class ConnectThread extends Thread {
        private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
        private final BluetoothDevice mmDevice;
        private String mSocketType;

        public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device, boolean secure) {
            mmDevice = device;
            BluetoothSocket tmp = null;
            mSocketType = secure ? "Secure" : "Insecure";

            // Get a BluetoothSocket for a connection with the
            // given BluetoothDevice
            try {
                if (secure) {
                    tmp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(
                            MY_UUID_SECURE);
                } else {
                    tmp = device.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(
                            MY_UUID_INSECURE);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Socket Type: " + mSocketType + "create() failed", e);
            }
            mmSocket = tmp;
        }

        public void run() {
            Log.i(TAG, "BEGIN mConnectThread SocketType:" + mSocketType);
            setName("ConnectThread" + mSocketType);

            // Always cancel discovery because it will slow down a connection
            mAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

            // Make a connection to the BluetoothSocket
            try {
                // This is a blocking call and will only return on a
                // successful connection or an exception
                mmSocket.connect();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // Close the socket
                try {
                    mmSocket.close();
                } catch (IOException e2) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "unable to close() " + mSocketType +
                            " socket during connection failure", e2);
                }
                connectionFailed();
                return;
            }

            // Reset the ConnectThread because we're done
            synchronized (BluetoothChatService.this) {
                mConnectThread = null;
            }

            // Start the connected thread
            connected(mmSocket, mmDevice, mSocketType);
        }

        public void cancel() {
            try {
                mmSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "close() of connect " + mSocketType + " socket failed", e);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * This thread runs during a connection with a remote device.
     * It handles all incoming and outgoing transmissions.
     */
    private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
        private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
        private final InputStream mmInStream;
        private final OutputStream mmOutStream;

        public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket, String socketType) {
            Log.d(TAG, "create ConnectedThread: " + socketType);
            mmSocket = socket;
            InputStream tmpIn = null;
            OutputStream tmpOut = null;

            // Get the BluetoothSocket input and output streams
            try {
                tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
                tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "temp sockets not created", e);
            }

            mmInStream = tmpIn;
            mmOutStream = tmpOut;
        }

        public void run() {
            Log.i(TAG, "BEGIN mConnectedThread");
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int bytes;

            // Keep listening to the InputStream while connected
            while (true) {
                try {
                    // Read from the InputStream
                    bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);

                    // Send the obtained bytes to the UI Activity
                    mHandler.obtainMessage(Constants.MESSAGE_READ, bytes, -1, buffer)
                            .sendToTarget();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "disconnected", e);
                    connectionLost();
                    // Start the service over to restart listening mode
                    BluetoothChatService.this.start();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        /**
         * Write to the connected OutStream.
         *
         * @param buffer The bytes to write
         */
        public void write(byte[] buffer) {
            try {
                mmOutStream.write(buffer);

                // Share the sent message back to the UI Activity
                mHandler.obtainMessage(Constants.MESSAGE_WRITE, -1, -1, buffer)
                        .sendToTarget();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Exception during write", e);
            }
        }

        public void cancel() {
            try {
                mmSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "close() of connect socket failed", e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```